# MatchIt: Full Matching - Long Vector Error

Tags: r, matching, propensity-score-matching

I am running an analysis to assess the land conservation policy impact on land use change at parcel level. To address the non-random nature of conservation program enrollment, I am running a matching analysis between treated and non-treated parcel level data. I am getting this error when I am trying to run a full matching using MatchIt  package.

```
Error in cbind(treatmentids, controlids) : 
long vectors not supported yet: ../include/Rinlinedfuns.h:535
```

The configuration I am using is:

```
m1.out <- matchit(formula = Y ~ X1 + X2 + ..... Xn, data = dataframe, 
                   method = "full", distance = 'glm', link = 'logit',
                   estimand = 'ATT', ratio = 1, pop.size = 16)
```

Where X1 .. Xn are continuous covariates, Y is a binary treatment variable. The dataset contains 121226 rows out of which 51693 are treatment and the rest are control samples.

I am running R (4.0.2) with MatchIt(4.3.4) on a windows machine. Genetic or nearest neighbor matching methods are running without any issues. I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help if you share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your data, so we can see what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error from `optmatch`. The problem is too big for `optmatch::fullmatch()`, the function `matchit()` calls with `method = "full"`, to handle. This is because `fullmatch()` does a search over all pairwise distances, which in this case is over 2.5 billion in number. The problem may simply be infeasible for full matching. See [here](https://github.com/markmfredrickson/optmatch/issues/209) for the same problem.

Some things you can try are to impose a very strict caliper, which reduces the number of eligible nodes, or add an exact matching constraint using the `exact` argument, which splits the problem into smaller chunks that may be more manageable. You can also try using subclassification with a large number of subclasses, which approximates full matching.

Also note that the `ratio` and `pop.size` arguments do nothing with full matching, so you should exclude them from your call to `matchit()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Noah! I have got a similar error (nc*nr resulting in too large a data) while using a caliper. As mentioned in the GitHub thread you shared, I will try to install the new version of optmatch to see if that helps. The subclasses method worked fine, however.